# Inno Setup - FileCopy use wildcard character in pathname

Tags: inno-setup, wildcard, pascal, file-copying, delphi

I'm trying to copy all database files over from a previous installation to a new installation, which has a new pathname.  The problem is that the installer will not know the names of the database files, so I'm trying to use a wildcard character.

I tried using TFileStream.Create(), but this was searching for a single file, such as "*.mdb", and I kept getting an error saying it couldn't find that file.  I also tried using FileCopy(), but it seems to simply fail and move on.  I even tried using [`Exec()`](https://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_exec.htm) to run it through command line, but it would just freeze the installation.

I've searched online a long time for an answer and read through a lot of the documentation.  I just need to know how I can use a wildcard character to copy files with unknown names.  Below are examples of what I've tried.

TFileStream.Create()

```
    OldDBs := 'C:\Users\seang\Desktop\Old\*.mdb';
    NewDBs := 'C:\Users\seang\Desktop\New\*.mdb';
    SourceDB:= TFileStream.Create(OldDBs, fmOpenRead);
    DestDB:= TFileStream.Create(NewDBs, fmCreate);
    DestDB.CopyFrom(SourceDB, SourceDB.Size);
    SourceDB.Free;
    DestDB.Free;
```

FileCopy()

```
    FileCopy('C:\Users\seang\Desktop\Old\*.mdb', 'C:\Users\seang\Desktop\New\*.mdb', True);
```

Command Line

```
    Exec('cmd.exe', 'COPY "C:\Users\seang\Desktop\Old\*.mdb" "C:\Users\seang\Desktop\New\*.mdb"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
```

Comment: See [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `FindFirst`, `FindNext`, and `FindClose` to iterate through the folder. You get each database name, and then copy it individually. An example of doing that in Pascal (Delphi) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5991040/62576). There's also an example of using them in the InnoSetup help file, in the `Support Functions Reference` section on `File System Functions`:

```
// This example counts all of the files (not folders) in the System directory.
var
  FilesFound: Integer;
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  FilesFound := 0;
  if FindFirst(ExpandConstant('{sys}\*'), FindRec) then begin
    try
      repeat
        // Don't count directories
        if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
          FilesFound := FilesFound + 1;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end;
  MsgBox(IntToStr(FilesFound) + ' files found in the System directory.',
    mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

You can change the loop above to look in the proper old folder for each `*.mdb`  (in the `FindFirst` call) and change the line that counts to a block that copies each file found into the new folder (using either `FileCopy` or a `TFileStream`, whichever you prefer).

Comment: Awesome!  Worked perfectly, thank you very much.  I searched FindFirst after viewing your post and found the Inno Setup documentation for this.  Guess I didn't look hard enough.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: For a complete code (including recursion), see [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848).

Answer (score 2):

Your command line attempt can work if you modify it a little:

```
Exec('cmd.exe', '/c COPY "C:\Users\seang\Desktop\Old\*.mdb" "C:\Users\seang\Desktop\New"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode);
```