# Copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Inno Setup Code section

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there any way to browse and recursively copy/move all files and subdirectories of a directory within the code section? (`PrepareToInstall`)

I need to ignore a specific directory, but using `xcopy` it ignores all directories `/default/`, for example, and I need to ignore a specific only.

The `Files` section is executed at a later time when needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To recursively copy a directory programmatically use:

```pascal
procedure DirectoryCopy(SourcePath, DestPath: string);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  SourceFilePath: string;
  DestFilePath: string;
begin
  if FindFirst(SourcePath + '\*', FindRec) then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          SourceFilePath := SourcePath + '\' + FindRec.Name;
          DestFilePath := DestPath + '\' + FindRec.Name;
          if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
          begin
            if FileCopy(SourceFilePath, DestFilePath, False) then
            begin
              Log(Format('Copied %s to %s', [SourceFilePath, DestFilePath]));
            end
              else
            begin
              Log(Format('Failed to copy %s to %s', [
                SourceFilePath, DestFilePath]));
            end;
          end
            else
          begin
            if DirExists(DestFilePath) or CreateDir(DestFilePath) then
            begin
              Log(Format('Created %s', [DestFilePath]));
              DirectoryCopy(SourceFilePath, DestFilePath);
            end
              else
            begin
              Log(Format('Failed to create %s', [DestFilePath]));
            end;
          end;
        end;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Failed to list %s', [SourcePath]));
  end;
end;
```

Add any filtering you need. See how the `.` and `..` are filtered.

---

Note that the function does not create the root `DestPath`. If you do not know if it exists, add this to be beginning of the code:

```pascal
if DirExists(DestPath) or CreateDir(DestPath) then
```

(then the similar code before the recursive `DirectoryCopy` call becomes redundant)

---

For an example of use, see my answers to questions:

- [Copying hidden files in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34050206/850848)
- [How to save a folder when user confirms uninstallation? (Inno Setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42684469/850848).