# Inno script for copying files

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

Inno procedure to copy one folder from one place to other by taking source file by prompt to user and destination in code itself

I tried filecopy function and everything nothing worked out

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62299905/850848

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Files with progress bar on a custom page of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299905/copy-files-with-progress-bar-on-a-custom-page-of-inno-setup)  I seems like a duplicate but there is very little detail in this question to evaluate any important distinctions.