# Using shell xcopy command in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to copy add-on folders/files from the `{app}` directory to a different folder in `Program Files` within an Inno Setup installer. I have written some code to execute a shell command to do so using `xcopy` but I cannot get it to work. I have tried all that I can think of permissions wise (`shellexecasoriginaluser`, `Flag`=`runasoriginaluser`, `PrivilegesRequired=admin`). If I type it by hand and run it in `cmd` it works fine, so one assumes it must be a permissions issue? Any ideas?

Code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "..\Dialogs\*";DestDir: "{app}\Dialogs"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs 64bit; AfterInstall: WriteExtensionsToInstallFolder();

[Code]

procedure WriteExtensionsToInstallFolder();
var  
  StatisticsInstallationFolder: string;
  pParameter: string;
  runline: string;
  ResultCode: integer;  
begin
  StatisticsInstallationFolder := SelectStatisticsFolderPage.Values[0];
  pParameter := '@echo off' + #13#10
  runline := 'xcopy /E /I /Y "' + ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Dialogs\*" "' + ExpandConstant(StatisticsInstallationFolder) + '\ext"'
  if not ShellExec('',runline, pParameter, '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Could not copy plugins' + IntToStr(ResultCode) ,mbError, mb_Ok);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `FileName` argument should be `xcopy` (or rather `xcopy.exe`) only.
- The rest of the command-line goes to the `Params` argument.
- The `echo off` parameter is nonsense.
- Using the [`ShellExec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec) for the `xcopy` is an overkill, use plain [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).

```pascal
Exec('xcopy.exe', '/E /I ...', ...)
```

---

Though for a better error control, you better use native Pascal Script functions:
[Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848)

---

And the last, the simplest and the best way, for your specific case, just use the `[Files]` section entry with a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "..\Dialogs\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Dialogs"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs 64bit;
Source: "..\Dialogs\*"; DestDir: "{code:GetStatisticsInstallationFolder}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs 64bit;

[Code]

function GetStatisticsInstallationFolder(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := SelectStatisticsFolderPage.Values[0];
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I toiled for hours over this

Comment: You are welcome. Though I've realized that there's yet better way for your speicific need. See my updated answer.