# How to save a folder when user confirms uninstallation? (Inno Setup)

Tags: backup, inno-setup, uninstallation, pascalscript

How can I save a backup copy of an specific folder to user desktop, when user confirms application uninstall?

I tried this without success... Maybe there is an easier way to do it without using code...

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    FileCopy('{app}\Profile\*', '{userdesktop}\Backup\Profile\', False);
  end;
end;
```

Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triggering the backup on `CurUninstallStepChanged(usUninstall)` is the best solution.

The problems you have are:

- The [`FileCopy` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filecopy) cannot copy folders.

  For that see [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848).
- You have to use the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) to resolve the `{app}` and the `{userdesktop}` constants.
- You have to create the target folder.

With use of the `DirectoryCopy` user function (from the question referenced above), you can do:

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  SourcePath: string;
  DestPath: string;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then
  begin
    SourcePath := ExpandConstant('{app}\Profile');
    DestPath := ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}\Backup\Profile');
    Log(Format('Backing up %s to %s before uninstallation', [
      SourcePath, DestPath]));
    if not ForceDirectories(DestPath) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to create %s', [DestPath]));
    end
      else
    begin
      DirectoryCopy(SourcePath, DestPath);
    end;
  end;
end;
```