# Backup external file before Inno Setup InstallDelete section

Tags: backup, inno-setup

I would make a backup of files and folders before the `[InstallDelete]` section deletes them

```
[Files]
Source: "{app}\res_mods\configs\wotstat\cache.json"; \
  DestDir: "{app}\_backup\res_mods_{#DateTime}\configs\wotstat\"; \
  Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist uninsneveruninstall 
Source: "{app}\res_mods\0.9.17.1\vehicles\*"; \
  DestDir:"{app}\_backup\res_mods_{#DateTime}\0.9.17.1\vehicles\"; \
  Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist createallsubdirs recursesubdirs uninsneveruninstall
```

This works fine. But, if i check

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\mods\*.*"; Tasks: cleanres
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\res_mods\*.*"; Tasks: cleanres
```

No files are saved

How I can made it work. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[InstallDelete]` section is processed (as one would expect) before the `[Files]` section. See the [installation order](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installorder).

You can code the backup in the [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged), that happens before the installation starts:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  SourcePath: string;
  DestPath: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    SourcePath := ExpandConstant('{app}\res_mods\0.9.17.1\vehicles');
    DestPath :=
      ExpandConstant('{app}\_backup\res_mods_{#DateTime}\0.9.17.1\vehicles');
    Log(Format('Backing up %s to %s before installation', [
      SourcePath, DestPath]));
    if not ForceDirectories(DestPath) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to create %s', [DestPath]));
    end
      else
    begin
      DirectoryCopy(SourcePath, DestPath);
    end;

    SourcePath := ExpandConstant('{app}\res_mods\configs\wotstat\cache.json');
    DestPath :=
      ExpandConstant('{app}\_backup\res_mods_{#DateTime}\configs\wotstat');
    if not ForceDirectories(DestPath) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Failed to create %s', [DestPath]));
    end
      else
    begin
      if not FileCopy(SourcePath, DestPath + '\cache.json', False) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Failed to copy %s', [SourcePath]));
      end
        else 
      begin
        Log(Format('Backed up %s', [SourcePath]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The code uses the `DirectoryCopy` function from the [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848).