# Backup previous installation in Inno Setup while excluding some folders (backup folder itself)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am creating an installer in order to update a service. My idea is:

1. Stop Service
2. Backup all files and folders in a folder named `backup`.
3. Remove all files and folders
4. Copy (install) new files and folders
5. Copy some files (configuration files) from `backup` overwriting new files created.

This is my code actually:

```
[Run]
;1. Stop service
Filename: "{sys}\sc.exe"; Parameters: "stop ""myService"

[Files]
;2. Create temporally backup
Source: {app}\*; Excludes: "backup"; DestDir: {app}\backup\backup{code:GetTodaysName}; \
    Flags: external skipifsourcedoesntexist recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

;Install new version.
Source: "{#MyInstalerPath}\bin\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

;Restore config files.
Source: "{app}\backup\backup{code:GetTodaysName}\myService.Configuration.xml"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  TodaysName : String;

function GetToday : String;
begin
  Result := GetDateTimeString ('yyyymmddhhnnss', '-', #0);
end;

function GetTodaysName (Param: String): String;
begin
  if ('' = TodaysName) then
  begin
    TodaysName := GetToday ();
  end;
  Result := TodaysName;
end;
```

I have problems in parts 2 and 3. I should avoid backup folder in `backup` process, but I can't use both `Excludes` and `external`.

Anyone can help with this issues?
Thanks

Comment: I've removed the subquestion on XML, as that's totally unrelated to the rest. Please ask a separate question for this one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Pascal Script to copy/backup the files, if you want to exclude some.

See [Inno Setup: Backup external file before install delete section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42691942/850848)

Except that you need to modify the `DirectoryCopy` function from [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848) to exclude the `backup` folder itself.

Just modify this line:

```pascal
if (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
```

to

```pascal
if (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') and
   (CompareText(FindRec.Name, 'backup') <> 0) then
```

---

*Though if the backup is "temporary", why don't you backup the files to `{tmp}`, instead of a subfolder of `{app}`? Then you won't have to exclude anything.*