# CurrentSourceFilename with wildcard Source

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using `AfterInstall` on a `[Files]` entry with a wildcard `Source` parameter. Calling `CurrentSourceFilename` simply gives me the source pattern -- not the actual file that is being processed. Is there any way to get the actual filename?

The following example would log `{code:DirName}\*.ext` once for each file, not `{code:DirName}\file1.ext`, `{code:DirName}\file2.ext` etc.

```
[Files]
Source: "{code:DirName}\*.ext"; Flags: external; AfterInstall: LogName
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure LogName;
begin
  Log(CurrentSourceFilename);
end;

function DirName(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := 'dir';
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's indeed no way to retrieve that information, when `external` flag is used - seems like a bug to me.

*Without `external` flag, you can find out a file name using [`CurrentFilename`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_currentfilename).*

---

Instead, you can code the file copy (including the logging) in Pascal script.

See [Inno Setup: copy folder, subfolders and files recursively in Code section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391915/850848).