# How can I replace a file after installation, in Innosetup?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

Only After the installer Has successfully been installed, I want to copy and replace with this folder in C:\program

```
[files]
;(replace with this folder)
Filename: {App}\folder DestDir: C:\program
```

Comment: What "this folder"? Is that a folder on a machine, where you build your installer? Or on the destination machine? Why you need to do it *after* the installation?

Comment: The folder is inside the installer.

Comment: Again, Why you need to do it *after* the installation?

Comment: because i'm modifiying a older version of my installer, so i will run that and than overwrite a file with my new installer

Comment: Then it would be easier to run the old installer before installation.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own function in the `[Code]`-section.

Call this function in `CurUninstallStepChanged` with `if ( CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall )`.

In this function you can copy the folder as described 
[in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391915/inno-setup-copy-folder-subfolders-and-files-recursively-in-code-section?lq=1)